Is there a liquid Scharnhorst effect generalizing the liquid Casimir effect?
Context:
This question originates as a generalization of this. The Casimir effect is an attraction between two conducting plates predicted by QED due to the exclusion of certain virtual photon frequencies between the plates.
The water analog is to have 2 water proof plates in a large vibrating container of water. Due to the lack of certain vibrational modes between the plates there is an apparent difference in pressure between the outside of the 2 plates and space between them and so the plates move towards each other in a way completely analogous to the Casimir Effect.
Question:
Does a water analog of the Scharnhorst effect exist?  To summarize briefly: the Scharnhorst effect essentially conjectures that the speed of light travelling normal to two conducting plates is faster than the usual speed of light outside of the two plates.
The water analog here would be: If we put two waterproof plates in a large vibrating container of water, is the speed of the waves, between the plates, in the direction normal to the plates faster than the speed of the waves generally outside the plates?
More broadly what I'm asking is "is the Scharnhorst effect a property of any system with a background of vibrations, or is it very specific to QED"? It does originate from studying the nonlinear action of QED so it's not so clear to me if liquid analogs can demonstrate it.
